# Running function after JUnit test runner

Tags: java, junit4, cucumber-junit, junit-runner

Is there a way to trigger some function to run after the junit or cucumber testrunner is done?
I want to run a function that picks up the test report produced and push it to a specific place.

I dont have any other way to do this since builds are done on buildservers and i have no access to the buildscrips so need to do this fron inside the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @AfterClass annotation may be.

Comment: Hmm not sure if reports are generated before or after.